# Restrict `expect` to stdin/stdout interaction only

Tags: scripting, security, expect

I need to accept job files from users, which would essentially consist of console interaction with a process I will be running for them. Naturally, the first idea that came to mind is to use `expect` scripts as job files:

```tcl
spawn process
expect "ready"
send "process DATA"
set timeout 100
expect {
    "done" {send_user "success"}
    timeout {send_user "failure"}
}
```

However, since I'd like to accept jobs automatically, I want to prevent users from doing something stupid or dangerous, like spawning 10 `sysbench` processes, or writing random files to the disk, or trying to read `/etc/passwd`. I want to restrict them to STDIN/STDOUT interactions with the process I spawn for them.

How would I go about this? So far my thoughts are:

- write my own "expect lite". Sounds feasible but silly and time-consuming.
- sanitize `expect` job files. Sounds complex and error-prone.
- invent my own safe language and translate it to `expect`. Feasible, but I'll have to provide documentation and tutorials so users can learn it.
- restrict job process with quota and permissions. Not really an option, since I want my `process` to use a fair amount of CPU time and create tmp files (which I'm confident it will clean up).
- give users interactive access to `process`. Not an option since jobs may have to sit in a queue for some time.

Is there something obvious I'm missing, like `expect` configuration parameter which restricts the scripts, or a similar tool I could use instead?

Comment: Expect is a general-purpose programming language (it's TCL plus a library).  I think you'll need to use an OS-level restricted environment — dedicated user, permissions, SELinux, etc.

Comment: The use case is unclear to me. Do you just need to do some validation on the contents of `process DATA`?

Comment: @glennjackman No, I need to make sure users only submit data via `send`, and don't use other features `expect` has to offer.

Comment: Who writes the expect scripts?

Comment: @glennjackman Users I don't entirely trust. Oh, and these don't have to be expect scripts, a different solution to batch the interaction via STDIN/STDOUT would probably do.

Comment: Read about Tcl "safe interpreters" . You'll be able to remove `exec` and other commands, and run untrusted code with fewer worries

Comment: Not sure if you can load expect into a safe interp. But a safe interp is just a stripped down version of Tcl.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, that looks very promising! It's a big topic for me though, as I've never used Tcl much. I'll self-answer if I manage to get this working, but it may take some time. I'll also happily upvote even a partial answer going in this direction.

Comment: @glennjackman I think I managed to get safe interp working. Would you mind taking a look at the code in my answer to see if I forgot something important?

Answer (score 1):

TCL safe interpreters do work with `expect`. To illustrate, I have created two scripts: `unsafe.exp` representing user-submitted file and `safe.exp`, which uses a safe interpreter to run `unsafe.exp`. Here's the code of `unsafe.exp`:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn whoami
expect {
    "user" { send_user "safe success\n" }
    "root" { send_user "unsafe success\n" }
}
```

Running `unsafe.exp` as `root` results in

```
# expect unsafe.exp
spawn whoami
root
unsafe success
```

Now, `safe.exp` will prevent the user from using dangerous commands like `spawn`, while still providing access to essential features like `send` and `expect`. Here's the code:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect

# create a safe interpreter
interp create -safe untrusted

# provide it with essetial expect functions
interp alias untrusted send_user {} send_user
interp alias untrusted send {} send
interp alias untrusted expect {} expect
interp alias untrusted interact {} interact

# censor the "spawn" function
# not providing it would be just as safe, but scripts using it would fail
proc safe_spawn {args} {
    puts "censored spawn"
}
interp alias untrusted spawn {} safe_spawn

# create a safe process to interact with
spawn sudo -u user whoami

# run unsafe.exp
untrusted invokehidden source unsafe.exp
```

Running `safe.exp` as root results in

```
# expect safe.exp
spawn sudo -u user whoami
censored spawn
user
safe success
```